# Sharepoint Search showing pagination but not showing results

Tags: 2016, search-results, sharepoint-search, paging

I have a search result webpart on one of my pages, which show the results from main and sub sites.

I am using Sharepoint 2016.

Based on my search, it should not see any results but I am getting empty result with Pagination.
[image: First Page]

When I click pagination there is no results till the last page.
[image: Last Page]

Please advice me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you modified the control display template? are you using custom display template?

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that you have the [Search Paging Web Part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2007/ms544775(v%3Doffice.12)) on the page but have accidentally removed or "closed" the [Search Results Web Part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-search-results-web-part).

First, check the page in webpart maintenance mode by appending "?contents=1" to the page URL.  If the listing on this page shows a closed results webpart, then you can re-open it from this same view.
 If it is not visible here, you will need to navigate back to regular view of your search page, then click Edit Page. With the search results page open in Edit mode, click "Add a Web Part". In the **Categories** group under the ribbon, click Search.In the  **Parts** group under the ribbon, click **Search Results**, then click **Add**.